Uniswap Universal Router giving error on execute swap
I'm trying to get the best route to convert my WETH to DAI, on an Anvil fork using an Arbitrum provider (through Infura).
anvil --fork-url https://arbitrum-mainnet.infura.io/v3/<api_key> --auto-impersonate

The router.route method (which I'm calling through an arbitrum mainnet provider instead of the fork) gives me the following methodParameters.:
const router = new AlphaRouter({
      chainId: CHAIN_ID,
      provider: mainnetProvider,
      gasPriceProvider: customGasPriceProvider,
    });

const swapOptions: SwapOptionsUniversalRouter = {
      type: SwapType.UNIVERSAL_ROUTER,
      recipient: WALLET_ADDRESS,
      slippageTolerance: SLIPPAGE_TOLERANCE, // Use the increased slippage tolerance
      deadline: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000 + 1800), // 30 minutes
      version: UniversalRouterVersion.V2_0,
    };

const route = await router.route(
      amountInCurrency,
      tokenOut,
      TradeType.EXACT_INPUT,
      swapOptions,
    );

---

Quote: {
  calldata: "0x24856bc30000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000f39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016345785d8a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d7a1480e25ad9e73a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b82af49447d8a07e3bd95bd0d56f35241523fbab1000bb8da10009cbd5d07dd0cecc66161fc93d7c9000da1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  value: "0x00",
  to: "0x5E325eDA8064b456f4781070C0738d849c824258"
}

On executing this transaction like below though (referring from https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/universal-router/technical-reference), I get a CALL_EXCEPTION error, which has no specific details. I confirmed that the contract is accessible and that the code exists using provider.getCode(). I'm using Uniswap's Universal Router (https://github.com/Uniswap/universal-router/blob/main/deploy-addresses/arbitrum.json), and get the same error on each of the mentioned router addresses. I have approved the WETH token contract for permit2, for the max possible amount. Also, I get the same error without the auto-impersonate flag on anvil as well.
Am I using the calldata wrongly here? Am I supposed to parse the Command string and call the execute method of the Uniswap router on my own? How can I further debug this?
 const txData: ethers.providers.TransactionRequest = {
      to: UNIVERSAL_ROUTER_ADDRESS,
      data: quote.methodParameters.calldata,
      value: quote.methodParameters?.value,
    };
 const DEFAULT_GAS_LIMIT = 210000;
 gasEstimate = ethers.BigNumber.from(DEFAULT_GAS_LIMIT); 

 const response = await signer.sendTransaction({
      ...txData,
      gasLimit,
    });

Error:
{
  reason: "transaction failed",
  code: "CALL_EXCEPTION",
  transactionHash: "0xa30df757e65bb4c6cb256442aa92f0ecb1e8c7b6f090ffd37b8cdcf3254b21a4",
  transaction: {
    type: 2,
    chainId: 42161,
    nonce: 3710,
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: "0x59682f00", _isBigNumber: true },
    maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: "0x59d10b76", _isBigNumber: true },
    gasPrice: null,
    gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: "0x03d860", _isBigNumber: true },
    to: "0xeC8B0F7Ffe3ae75d7FfAb09429e3675bb63503e4",
    value: BigNumber { _hex: "0x00", _isBigNumber: true },
    data: "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",
    accessList: [],
    hash: "0xa30df757e65bb4c6cb256442aa92f0ecb1e8c7b6f090ffd37b8cdcf3254b21a4",
    v: 1,
    r: "0x4f08707258d9b26676e7bf5569188f350483eb1db4ee6f637375b1ecbcc7fc7d",
    s: "0x4e9cd2da83097ddf5ad5af6fc1a26bd580d631ca7a2428644f720e05cb96ac46",
    from: "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266",
    confirmations: 0,
    wait: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  receipt: {
    to: "0xeC8B0F7Ffe3ae75d7FfAb09429e3675bb63503e4",
    from: "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266",
    contractAddress: null,
    transactionIndex: 0,
    root: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    gasUsed: BigNumber { _hex: "0x01c5ae", _isBigNumber: true },
    logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    blockHash: "0x508005f081deeb7dfdbc89dc58956c782b611a38ec9d8ff6c193206c8a9b0899",
    transactionHash: "0xa30df757e65bb4c6cb256442aa92f0ecb1e8c7b6f090ffd37b8cdcf3254b21a4",
    logs: [],
    blockNumber: 21025547,
    confirmations: 245660339,
    cumulativeGasUsed: BigNumber { _hex: "0x01c5ae", _isBigNumber: true },
    effectiveGasPrice: BigNumber { _hex: "0x59960f74", _isBigNumber: true },
    status: 0,
    type: 2,
    byzantium: true
  }
}


did you approve permit2?

I did. Not sure what's causing this still
